# SQL ManyToMany. How select product from category '1'

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Hello i'm beginner in SQL and i do not understand how to:

```
select product from category where id='1'.
```

I have 3 tables:

```
product: id | name
category: id | name
category_product: product_id | category_id
```

Comment: "id='1'" which id? product or category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want?
Make use of `join`

```
select 
   name 
from product pr 
join category_product cp on (cp.product_id = pr.id) 
where cp.catagory_id = '1'
```

Comment: Yes. that's what I need. 
Thank you

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь Glad to hear:).  Mark it as a answer. If it helped...

Answer (score 0):

Join your tables on their keys.

```
SELECT p.name
FROM product p
INNER JOIN category_product cp ON p.id = cp.product_id
INNER JOIN category c ON cp.category_id - c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
```